# How to plot graphs from equations

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph

I am trying to replicate some graphs from 3 equations.

My equation are shown in my python code below
The first two equations are plotted on the 1st graph
The first equation and the 3rd equation are plotted on the 2nd graph
The last two equations are plotted on the 3rd graph

My parameters are:
k1 = a range of values, k2=1, n1=3, n2=3, K1=0.3, K2=0.3, b1=0, b2=0.05

i'm unsure about how to plot this on a graph. any help would be great. thanks
*note that i am a python beginner and have basic knowledge of coding*

here's my code so far:

```css
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


rateinact= k1*X

rateact12= k2*(b2*(K2**n2/(K2**n2 + X**n2)) + (X**n2/(K2**n2 + X**n2))*(1-X)

Rateinact2 = k1*(B1*((X**n1)/(K1**n1+X**n1))+((K1**n1)/(K1**n1+X**n1)))*(X)

#define parameters
k1 = []
k2=1
n1=3
n2=3
K1=0.3
K2=0.3
b1=0
b2=0.05
#graph 1
plt.plot(inact, 'r')
plt.plot(act12, 'b')
plt.ylabel('Rate of A inactivation or activation')
plt.xlabel('Fraction of activated A)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You need to define variables before you use them in python. Also, `B1` is never defined, and you're missing a `)` and a close `'`

Answer (score 0):

The trick you seem to be missing is how to make a range of values. This can be easily done with `np.linspace` since you're already using numpy.

```
x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = x**2 + 3*x + 4
plt.plot(x,y,'g-')
```

Or, for your specific example, with the syntax errors removed (I had to guess a little on what some values were):

-- EDIT --

I see now a little better what you wanted. Here's a quick demo of how you might accomplish this (I'm using subfigures instead of separate figures, but the idea is the same):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

k1 = np.linspace(0,1,5)
k2=1
n1=3
n2=3
K1=0.3
K2=0.3
beta1=0
beta2=0.05
x = np.linspace(0,1)
def r_inact_1loop(x,k1=1):
    return k1*x
def r_activation(x,k1=1):
    return k2*(beta2*K2**n2/(K2**n2+x**n2) + x**n2/(K2**n2+x**n2))*(1-x)
def r_inact_2loop(x,k1=1):
    return k1*(beta1*x**n1/(K1**n1+x**n1) + K1**n1/(K1**n1+x**n1))*x
#define parameters

#graph 1
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,3)
ax1.set_xlabel('Fraction of activated A')
ax2.set_xlabel('Fraction of activated A')
ax3.set_xlabel('Fraction of activated A')
ax1.set_ylabel('Rate of A inactivation or activation')
ax2.set_ylabel('Rate of A inactivation or activation')
ax3.set_ylabel('Rate of A inactivation or activation')
for k in k1:
    ax1.plot(x,r_inact_1loop(x,k),label='in1 k1={:.1f}'.format(k))
    ax1.plot(x,r_activation(x,k),label='ac k1={:.1f}'.format(k))
    ax1.legend(loc='best')
    ax2.plot(x,r_inact_1loop(x,k),label='in1 k1={:.1f}'.format(k))
    ax2.plot(x,r_inact_2loop(x,k),label='in2 k1={:.1f}'.format(k))
    ax1.set_xlabel('Fraction of activated A')
    ax2.legend(loc='best')
    ax3.plot(x,r_activation(x,k),label='ac k1={:.1f}'.format(k))
    ax3.plot(x,r_inact_2loop(x,k),label='in2 k1={:.1f}'.format(k))
    ax3.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

--ADDENDUM--

If you want the cool shading of the plots you were looking at, here's the code for that

```
ax2.fill_between(x,r_inact_1loop(x,k1[0]),r_inact_1loop(x,k1[-1]))
ax3.fill_between(x,r_inact_2loop(x,k1[0]),r_inact_2loop(x,k1[-1]))
```

Comment: See [the tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) if you want to get more information on how to use matplotlib.

Comment: thank you, the graphs are meant to look like this:http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2832910/figure/F2/

Comment: @py500 I have added more information to help match your goal. If you want to get an exact match of the graphs, you might look at matplotlib's `plt.text` and `plt.annotate` functions.